# java programmer learning python: string split and join

Tags: python, api

Can someone explain to me why in python when we want to join a string we write:

```
'delim'.join(list)
```

and when we want to split a string we write:

```
str.split('delim')
```

coming from java it seems that one of these is backwards because in java we write:

```
//split:
str.split('delim');
//join
list.join('delim');
```

**edit:**
you are right. join takes a list. (though it doesnt change the question)

Can someone explain to me the rationale behind this API?

Comment: `str.join('delim');`? Really?

Comment: You usually write `'delim'.join(sequence)`, not `'delim'.join(str)`.  The latter does something rather strange – it joins the characters of the string by `'delim'`.

Comment: You seem to be using `str` as a variable name here, which is rather confusing.

Comment: There is no str.join("delim") method in java as far as I know.

Comment: Because every programming language needs at least one feature that makes you say "WTF".

Comment: Semicolons are unnecessary in python code.

Comment: @mgilson: that is a java example ;)

Comment: @mkoryak -- Ahh.  Got it.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join only makes sense when joining some sort of iterable.  However, since iterables don't necessarily contain all strings, putting `join` as a method on an iterable doesn't make sense.  (what would you expect the result of `[1,"baz",my_custom_object,my_list].join("foo")` to be?) The only other place to put it is as a string method with the understanding that everything in the iterable is going to be a string.  Additionally, putting `join` as a string method allows it to be used with any iterable -- tuples, lists, generators, custom objects which support iteration or even strings.

Also note that you are completely free to split a string in the same way that you join it:

```
list_of_strings='this, is , a, string, separated, by , commas.'.split(',')
```

Of course, the utility here isn't quite as easy to see.

Comment: a_string.split(delim) returns str types. The OP first uses the string split method thus returning a list of strings

Comment: @DevPlayer -- while that's true, it doesn't make sense to have a method on an iterable which only works on some (not all) instances.  It does make sense to have a method on a string which only works with some inputs however as that's the behavior you expect with any function (put garbage in, get garbage out).

Comment: most coders who want to join [1,"bax", object, alist] would normally want returned object of congruent concatenations of list elements. Therefore each object type would need to be individually converted to a certain expected type object. Symantically when coders "join" in Python we think of string concatenation as opposed to "adding" or "appending" which Python coders expect different kinds of binary operations of list objects then "joining".

Comment: That's an implicit conversion.  What type do you cast everything in the list to?  how do you specify/guess that within the join method?  I suppose you could specify a keyword for the type to cast to, but any default you specified would be completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/faq/design.html#why-is-join-a-string-method-instead-of-a-list-or-tuple-method

From the source:

> join() is a string method because in using it you are telling the
>   separator string to iterate over a sequence of strings and insert
>   itself between adjacent elements. This method can be used with any
>   argument which obeys the rules for sequence objects, including any new
>   classes you might define yourself.
>
> Because this is a string method it can work for Unicode strings as
>   well as plain ASCII strings. If join() were a method of the sequence
>   types then the sequence types would have to decide which type of
>   string to return depending on the type of the separator.

Answer (score 1):

So that you don't have to reimplement the join operation for every sequence type you create. Python uses **protocols**, not types, as its main behavioral pattern, and so every sequence can be expected to act the same even though they don't derive from an existing sequence class.